# Sharing variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

In following code, I am taking input
of an AJAX call into a function called
`plr()`. I want to detect when loading
is complete using the `done` variable.
But main thread is locking the
variable and the script hangs the
browser. If I put the alert in the
commented place, the purpose is
served. So, what other way can I use
to do the same?

```
function openX() {
            LoadContentInto("Default.aspx", plr);
            var obj = null;
            done = false;
            function plr() {
                x = this.AJAXObject.responseText;
                t = x.indexOf('{')
                n = parseInt(x.substring(0, t));
                s = x.substring(t, n + t);
                p = eval('(' + s + ')');
                obj = p;
                done = true;
            }
            while (done != true)
            { // alert("hello"); 
            }
            alert(done);
        }
```

Comment: What library are you using? I am unfamiliar with those names.

Comment: its teleiotes. My own library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to make synchronous your ajax call, so there's no need to create an empty (blocking) while. the callback `plr()` will be executed on successful response, then remaining data will be called inside that callback

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Snippets:_Synchronous_AJAX

Comment: @fcalderan This is good. But is this any way I can implement an event listener like above with asynch call?

Comment: @Šime Vidas, I suppose this depends by purposes you have to reach with that code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not wait that actively for the result. When the AJAX call is successfully finished you have the callback function called. In your case it seems that it is `plr` (although it is not clear what `LoadContentInto` exactly does).

It seems you have a temptation to make the AJAX success callback synchronous. Sometimes I used to have such passions, but so far it always showed up that there is an asynchronous way as well.

Maybe you want something like that:

```
function openX() {
  LoadContentInto("Default.aspx", plr);
  var obj = null;
  var done = false; // you have your variable global! Make it local!
  function plr() {
    x = this.AJAXObject.responseText;
    // ...
    // put your code here
    // ...
    alert("Done!");
    done = true;
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (!done) {
      alert("Please wait!");
      // Does the response and/or the operation after the responseText arives take a long time?
      // Based on that decide how to inform the user
    }
  }, 100); // Set the timeout to right value.. based on your needs
}
```

Few comments to your code:

- you have `done` declared as a global variable, it is very likely that it should be local
- `while (done != true)` is much cleaner as `while (!done)`

Comment: Though this might work in some cases, we will either lose response or time when we use a constant value for time. What I want is application of an event listener. Something that happens when you flash an alert in current thread (but without displaying alert of course)..

Comment: And please forgive my code. I was just playing with client for json.net not part of any library

Comment: @mihsathe the codes get better by practice. I do not understand your problem from the previous comments. JavaScript likes callbacks, it is quite about listening different events. That's common in JS. When an AJAX request is successfully completed, there is also a callback for this, that's what you call.